# scons can't find #include files

Tags: c++, scons, godot

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPcSfXsoArQ&list=WL&index=3&t=310s) tutorial on setting up gdnative.

I have installed c++ tools through visual studio, python 3.2, and scons 4.1.0

I am stuck trying to get scons to build [this](https://github.com/BastiaanOlij/gdnative_cpp_example) gdnative example. The issue I'm having appears to be scons not being able to find #include files. I have tried using a relative file paths to a sub directory `godot-cpp/`, relative paths to a sibling directory `../godot-cpp/`, and using a full path to the sibling directory `E:/Projects/Godot Projects/Units/godot-cpp/` but I am getting the same error every time. I have provided a screenshot to show the file structure. I am running scons from `X64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`

Edit - have now also tried while running as administrator, same error

Top Left: The project I am trying to build and the cpp files I need to include in sibling directories.

Top Right: The contents of the project folder. The `godot-cpp/` subdirectory is a copy of the folder of the same name from the Top Left.

Bottom Left: Contents of `godot-cpp/`

Bottom Right: Contents of `godot-cpp/godot-headers`. The highlighted file is the one it can't seem to find.

[image: File structure]

Relative path to sub directory:

```
E:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\gdnative_cpp_example>scons platform=windows
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fosrc\gdexample.obj /c src\gdexample.cpp /TP /nologo -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -D_WINDOWS -W3 -GR -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -EHsc -D_DEBUG -MDd /I. /Igodot-cpp\godot_headers /Igodot-cpp\include /Igodot-cpp\include\core /Igodot-cpp\include\gen /Isrc
gdexample.cpp
godot-cpp\include\core\Godot.hpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdnative_api_struct.gen.h': No such file or directory
scons: *** [src\gdexample.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Relative path to sibling directory:

```
E:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\gdnative_cpp_example>scons platform=windows
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fosrc\gdexample.obj /c src\gdexample.cpp /TP /nologo -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -D_WINDOWS -W3 -GR -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -EHsc -D_DEBUG -MDd /I. "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\godot_headers" "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include" "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include\core" "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include\gen" /Isrc
gdexample.cpp
E:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include\core\Godot.hpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdnative_api_struct.gen.h': No such file or directory
scons: *** [src\gdexample.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Full path to sibling directory:

```
E:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\gdnative_cpp_example>scons platform=windows
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fosrc\gdexample.obj /c src\gdexample.cpp /TP /nologo -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -D_WINDOWS -W3 -GR -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -EHsc -D_DEBUG -MDd /I. "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\godot_headers" "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include" "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include\core" "/IE:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include\gen" /Isrc
gdexample.cpp
E:\Projects\Godot Projects\Units\godot-cpp\include\core\Godot.hpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdnative_api_struct.gen.h': No such file or directory
scons: *** [src\gdexample.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

It's getting stuck following the include statement from `Godot.hpp line 7` to `gdnative_api_struct.gen.h`. It looks like it can resolve the path just fine but it can't open them for some reason.

SConstruct file - Came with the project I'm trying to build. Only modification was changing the paths to `godot-cpp/` and `godot-cpp/headers/`.

```
#!python
import os, subprocess

opts = Variables([], ARGUMENTS)

# Gets the standard flags CC, CCX, etc.
env = DefaultEnvironment()

# Define our options
opts.Add(EnumVariable('target', "Compilation target", 'debug', ['d', 'debug', 'r', 'release']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('platform', "Compilation platform", '', ['', 'windows', 'x11', 'linux', 'osx']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('p', "Compilation target, alias for 'platform'", '', ['', 'windows', 'x11', 'linux', 'osx']))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('use_llvm', "Use the LLVM / Clang compiler", 'no'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_path', 'The path where the lib is installed.', 'demo/bin/'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_name', 'The library name.', 'libgdexample', PathVariable.PathAccept))

# Local dependency paths, adapt them to your setup
# These next two lines are where I changed the paths       <-----------------
godot_headers_path = "../godot-cpp/godot_headers/"
cpp_bindings_path = "../godot-cpp/"
cpp_library = "libgodot-cpp"

# only support 64 at this time..
bits = 64

# Updates the environment with the option variables.
opts.Update(env)

# Process some arguments
if env['use_llvm']:
    env['CC'] = 'clang'
    env['CXX'] = 'clang++'

if env['p'] != '':
    env['platform'] = env['p']

if env['platform'] == '':
    print("No valid target platform selected.")
    quit();

# Check our platform specifics

# I'm using windows so I cut the other options for readability

if env['platform'] == "windows":
    env['target_path'] += 'win64/'
    cpp_library += '.windows'
    # This makes sure to keep the session environment variables on windows,
    # that way you can run scons in a vs 2017 prompt and it will find all the required tools
    env.Append(ENV = os.environ)

    env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-DWIN32', '-D_WIN32', '-D_WINDOWS', '-W3', '-GR', '-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS'])
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-EHsc', '-D_DEBUG', '-MDd'])
    else:
        env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-O2', '-EHsc', '-DNDEBUG', '-MD'])

if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
    cpp_library += '.debug'
else:
    cpp_library += '.release'

cpp_library += '.' + str(bits)

# make sure our binding library is properly includes
env.Append(CPPPATH=['.', godot_headers_path, cpp_bindings_path + 'include/', cpp_bindings_path + 'include/core/', cpp_bindings_path + 'include/gen/'])
env.Append(LIBPATH=[cpp_bindings_path + 'bin/'])
env.Append(LIBS=[cpp_library])

# tweak this if you want to use different folders, or more folders, to store your source code in.
env.Append(CPPPATH=['src/'])
sources = Glob('src/*.cpp')

library = env.SharedLibrary(target=env['target_path'] + env['target_name'], source=sources)

Default(library)

# Generates help for the -h scons option.
Help(opts.GenerateHelpText(env))
```

Comment: your output doesn't seem to match your SConstruct: `/Igodot_cpp\godot_headers` etc. but  you've got this in the file: `godot_headers_path = "../godot-cpp/godot_headers/"` - with the needed `..` part. Can you check that everything you've posted is consistent?  If it is, you may end up having to use an absolute path to the "system headers".

Comment: In general it's a lot easier to read copy/pasted output from your shell than to try and read a screenshot. Please paste that output instead?

Comment: Why did you change the example SConstruct's paths to ../godot-cpp instead of what's in the example "godot-cpp"?

Comment: @bdaddog I changed it to follow along with the tutorial. As I said in the post, leaving it in the sub directory was giving me the same error.

Comment: @MatsWichmann are you saying the output suggests it's looking in `/Igodot_cpp\godot_headers`? I never did anything with an 'I' in the path, just `godot-cpp` in two different directories. Double checked the SConstruct file and it doesn't have a reference to IGodot-anything. I also tried absolute paths but that somehow seems like it worked less? I edited the post and pasted the output.

Comment: The `/I` is added by SCons as it processes `CPPPATH`, what's flagging for me is you seem to be passing `../something/else` there and it's being expanded to `/Isomething/else` - that is, without the leading `../` - that's why I was asking if everything was consistent with your post.

Comment: @MatsWichmann I think you were right about the inconsistancy. I probably took the screenshot when I was running it with the sub directory referenced but it was a copy of the same files just in a slightly different place. I have rewritten most of the post and included the output from 3 different tests now. It looks like it can resolve the path just fine but can't open the file for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this exact same problem today. On the line you changed in your SConstruct file you reference the godot headers directory (the one which contains `gdnative_api_struct.gen.h`) as `godot_headers`, but in your file system this folder is called `godot-headers` (`-` not `_`). Because of this scons cannot find the file. Changing the directory's name in the file system to `godot_headers` solved the problem for me.

Comment: I can't believe I spent two weeks tryig to fix a typo. Thanks.